# How to pass arguments to Elisp function?

Tags: emacs

I have this keymap to flush empty lines like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-T") (lambda () (interactive) (flush-lines "^[[:space:]]*$")))
```

But this doesn't work over a region. Unrelated lines out of the region are getting merged. But when I select a region and manually try M-x flush-lines RET ^[[:space:]]*$ RET, it works as expected.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function can be called interactively or non-interactively (this is in fact a little bit more complex, but that's a good enough approximation). The interactive calling mode is used to bind some function arguments from the current environment, or by interacting with the user. The non-interactive mode is the normal calling mode when you write in Emacs Lisp.

Typically, the interactive behaviour is declared using an `(interactive ...)` form after the docstring, but in the particular case of `flush-lines`, the behaviour is partly automated by an `interactive` spec, and partly hardcoded (for the region part). You can ask Emacs whether the current code is executed interactively by calling `called-interactively-p`, but as the doc say, it is encouraged to have another optional argument that indicates whether the call is interactive.

The function signature is:

```
(flush-lines REGEXP &optional RSTART REND INTERACTIVE)
```

`RSTART` and `REND` are the starting and ending position of the current region, as integers. They can also be `nil`. The last parameter indicates whether the call is interactive.

When you call `flush-lines` from your anonymous function, you are calling it non-interactively, which means you need to pass arguments explicitly to the functions.

For this function, you can simply call it as follows:

```
(flush-lines "^[[:space:]]*$" nil nil t)
```

This makes the function behaves as-if called interactively, in which case the region is computed automatically since the start and end argument are nil.

In the general case, what you would do is have your own `(interactive "r")` declaration, and add two parameters to the anonymous function. For example, in the `*scratch*` buffer, you can evalue this expression:

```
(call-interactively
  (lambda (beg end)
    (interactive "r")
    (list beg end)))
```

Then, the result is a list of cursor positions, that represents your region.
In your case you would call `(flush-lines "^[[:space:]]*$" beg end)`, for example.

Comment: FWIW, I don't understand what you're trying to say with this sentence: *"Typically, the interactive behaviour is declared using an (interactive ...) form after the docstring, **but in the particular case of flush-lines, the behaviour is hard-coded**"*. There's nothing hard-coded about the interactive behavior, AFAICT, and it *is* declared using an `(interactive...)` spec.

Comment: interactive "r" was very helpful!

Comment: @Drew I expected the code to be entirely defined by an interacive spec, but then I tried to see how it was implemented and the existing interactive spec has a progn with two expressions (https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/replace.el#L882); a check and the prompt for the regex. But the part that computes `rstart` and `rend` is done in the following `if`. I probably expressed myself badly, I was focused on the *region* part when writing that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's bad coding, IMHO. The doc string should at least say what `nil` values for `RSTART` and `REND` mean/do. You might want to update your answer to say something more like what you say in your comment. (Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions and answers should suffice for readers to learn.)